# Problem with Dojo Tree

Tags: dojo

I have implemented Dojo tree, it is working fine till certain levels of sub-tree/sub-node.After fetching of 250-300 nodes..its giving error msg: "A script on this page is cause Internet Explorer to run slowly.If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive."...wht is the problem here..?

Answer (score 0):

In your case it seems that the data been loaded is causing too much JavaScript execution to happen.This is crossing the browser JavaScript execution threshold.
I have faced this type of issue when we DojoX Grid used to load data >500 records and the way to workaround this to load only relevant data (one page at a time) on the client.On scrolling of grid, you can fetch the next page.

In your case your can defer loading sub-trees and leaf until the user clicks on Expand node option.There maybe other data stores that may provide such behavior in Dojo.